# Are the triangles in DelaunayMesh oriented ccw?

Tags: computational-geometry, implementation-details, mesh

`MeshCells[R, 2]` returns the triangles from `R=DelaunayMesh[pts]`, where `pts` is a list of 2D points. My (limited) experiments indicate the triangle vertices are listed in counterclockwise order, which is exactly what I need. But I cannot find in the documentation a statement that this is a guaranteed property of `DelaunayMesh` and `MeshCells`. Is it in fact guaranteed?

Of course I could reorient them if ccw is not guaranteed.

(I'm using Mathematica 10.4.0.0.)

Comment: @user21 to the rescue? (user21 = resident expert on all things mesh).

Comment: I don't think that it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user21 says it isn't guaranteed that the vertices will be in counter-clockwise order, but I can't find a counter-example.

Using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10298685/4712538) we can make a little function that tests a polygon for whether its vertices are CCW

```
ccwQ[list_List] := 
 Positive@Total[Subtract @@@ (list RotateLeft[Reverse /@ list])]
ccwQ[poly_Polygon] := ccwQ@First@poly
ccwQ[mesh_MeshRegion] := And @@ (ccwQ /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2])
ccwQ[mesh_BoundaryMeshRegion] := 
 And @@ (ccwQ /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2])
```

Check that it works,

```
ccwQ /@ {Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]}
(* {True, False} *)
```

And then apply it to 50 examples of random 800-point `DelaunayMesh` regions, verifying that every single triangle is CCW:

```
In[119]:= Table[ccwQ@DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[1, {800, 2}]], {50}]

Out[119]= {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
```

This seems to be general for the `MeshRegion` objects.  It works on `VoronoiMesh`:

```
ccwQ@VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {8000, 2}]]
(* True *)
```

as well as `DiscretizeRegion` results:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[x^3 - y^7 <= 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}}]]
ccwQ@%
ccwQ@DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I haven't looked at the underlying code to see if it is guaranteed to always be true, but it **seems** to always be true.  Chime in if you can find a counter-example

Comment: I also have tested ccw orientation on random examples (less thoroughly than you) without finding a counterexample.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if the tetrahedra in a 3D Delaunay triangulation are also consistently oriented.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke - how would you define orientation for points in 3D?  In order for the points in the polygons to have a CW or CCW orientation, you have to specify the side you are observing from, right?  What would the analogous metric be for the tetrahedron points?

Comment: @Jason, a usual convention is for the tetrahedron to have its face normals pointing away from its centroid. FWIW, `Sign[Det[PadRight[{p1, p2, p3}, {Automatic, 3}, 1]]] == 1` is a relatively compact way to test if the points of a triangle are oriented anticlockwise.

Comment: @JasonB: I would require that the volume determinant from $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ in order is positive. This is the same as requiring the four face normals to point outward.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke - Using J.M.'s method, you can evaluate `Negative@Det[PadRight[First@#, {Automatic, 4}, 1]] & /@ 
 MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[10, {250, 3}]], 3]` and it seems to always give `True`.  I don't know why it's negative and not positive, I don't fully understand the method).

Comment: The construction `Det[PadRight[{p1, ..., pk}, {Automatic, k}, 1]]` is (up to a factor) effectively the signed content (area in 2D, volume in 3D) of a simplex. Positive content has the implications me and Joseph previously gave.

Comment: @J.M. Okay, so running that on the `Tetrahedron`s in a 3D Delaunay mesh gives a negative determinant every time.

Comment: Then that means at least one face of the tetrahedron has its normal pointing towards the centroid.

Comment: That seems weird, maybe I ran the function incorrectly.  Do you get the same result from `Tetrahedron[{{3.10011, 1.02848, 2.92798}, {3.14553, 1.31258, 
   2.10373}, {3.83303, 0.240916, 2.1885}, {3.52785, 0.504389, 
   1.79437}}]`?